# Many calls to the server

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I use `Selector`, and channels (`ServerSocketChannel`, `DatagramChannel`), to create udp/tcp heandler in the same socket. When I send packet of `DatagramPacket` to the server, Server register many selectors (2-8, each time different), and each time, the server handles these keys. So, this queries have empty fields after use `trim()`, but one of these keys has a text of query.

**Server**

```
public class Server extends Thread {
public void run() {
    SocketAddress port = new InetSocketAddress(ReaderProperty.getPropertyPort());
    try {
        Selector selector = Selector.open();

        ServerSocketChannel tcpServer = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        tcpServer.socket().bind(port);
        tcpServer.configureBlocking(false);
        tcpServer.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        DatagramChannel udpServer = DatagramChannel.open();
        udpServer.socket().bind(port);
        udpServer.configureBlocking(false);
        udpServer.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

        while(true) {
            try {
                selector.select();

                Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();

                for (Iterator<SelectionKey> i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                    SelectionKey key = i.next();
                    i.remove();

                    Channel c = key.channel();

                    if (key.isAcceptable() && c == tcpServer) {
                        new TCPResponse(tcpServer.accept().socket()).start();
                    } else if (key.isReadable() && c == udpServer) {
                        new UDPResponse(udpServer, key.channel()).start();
                    }
                }

                keys.clear();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**UDPRequest**

```
public class UDPRequest {
public UDPRequest(String server, int port, String query) {
    DatagramSocket client = null;
    try {
        client = new DatagramSocket();

        byte[] sendByte = query.getBytes();
        byte[] receiveByte = new byte[32];

        DatagramPacket sender = new DatagramPacket(sendByte, sendByte.length, InetAddress.getByName(server), port);
        client.send(sender);

        DatagramPacket receiver = new DatagramPacket(receiveByte, receiveByte.length);
        client.receive(receiver);

        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
        buf.clear();
        buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(receiver.getData());

        String receiveLine = new String(buf.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")).trim();

        System.out.println("IP address or DOMAIN NAME: " + receiveLine);

        if (receiveLine.equals("true")) {
            new TCPRequest(server, port, query);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    if (client != null) {
        client.close();
    }
}
```

**UDPResponse**

```
public class UDPResponse extends Thread {
private DatagramChannel channel = null;
private SelectableChannel selectableChannel = null;

public UDPResponse(DatagramChannel channel, SelectableChannel selectableChannel) {
    super("UDPResonse");
    this.channel = channel;
    this.selectableChannel = selectableChannel;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
        buf.clear();
        InetSocketAddress address = (InetSocketAddress) ((DatagramChannel) selectableChannel).receive(buf);

        String inputLine = new String(buf.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        String outputLine = Utils.processCommand(inputLine.trim());

        buf.clear();
        try {
            buf.put(outputLine.getBytes());
        } catch (BufferOverflowException overflow) {
            buf.put("true".getBytes());
        }
        buf.flip();

        try {
            channel.send(buf, address);
        } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Why I make one query to the server, but the server gets 2-8 connections at a time?

**UPD:**
*I found a solution only if these empty requests are just ignored:*

```
if (inputLine.trim().length() != 0) {
    //process...
}
```

Comment: Could it be the `new TCPRequest(server, port, query);` at the end of the `UDPRequest` constructor? Why are you creating a TCPRequest in the UDPRequest's constructor anyways?

Comment: Also, I would suggest that you move all the non-setup-natured things from the constructor to a method. Constructors should not have side effects, like sending the packet. That's the responsibility of a method.

Comment: TCPRequest is called in the Client. Client send query. If response of query is biggest of 8 bytes (i.e), then I have TC flag and these means, I want to reconnect to the Server from TCP protocol. So, it can't be because of this.

Comment: @cubrr Thank you, I took your advice.

Comment: 'Create UDP/TCP handler in the same socket' is a contradiction in terms, and there is no such class as `ServletSocketChannel`. Allocating a `ByteBuffer` immediately before reassigning it to the result of `wrap()` and then doing nothing with it beyond getting back the original byte array is pointless, as is using threads with non-blocking sockets. Your question doesn't make sense and neither does your code.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for your comments, I soon 5 o'clock in the morning, and I haven't slept. Not follow.

Comment: 'Not follow' is also meaningless, but the best advice I can give you about working till 5am, having been there a few times in my youth, is 'don't'. Go home, do something else, have a life, get some sleep. The answer will come while in the shower, or shaving. Or else there isn't one. In either case at least you haven't wasted your life for that night.